# automatical resize of a backgorund image

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

hello i have a problem with using my background graphics.

the structure of the site is the following:

header contains two colors with a fixed height of 100px.
mainframe should contain a sliced image with a variable height.
footer contains one color and has also a fixed height of 100px.

so my sliced image has a height of 550px and will fit exactly between header and footer in case the content would not be larger.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div id="header">header</div>

        <div id="mainframe">INSIDE HERE SHOULD BE PLACED THE SLICED IMAGE BUT THE CONTENT IS MORE THAN 550PX</div>

        <div class="push"></div><!--Push for sticky footer-->

</div><!--Wrapper -->

    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/qUzjX/)

now the problem is, that my content will be larger than 550px and because of a fading colour there will be a hard edgde and you can see where the image ends. so i thought it would be nice when that sliced background image could automatically be resized.

is there a way to realize that by using css?

thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: unfortunately, there isn't a way to resize background images with CSS.

Often, there's a clever workaround using the background-repeat:repeat-x; or background-repeat:repeat-y; properties, and using a carefully sliced background image.

If you have an example of the image, I may be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
background-size: 100% Auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
background-size:cover;
```